# Is os module doing something here? Input not getting appended to my list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry for the general question I just don't really know what else to ask. So my problem is that nothing appends to my "num_list". I was thinking maybe it has to do with the clear function I made? Is it maybe resetting my list so that nothing gets appended? I'm sure it's just something simple that I overlooked. Would really appreciate some help, and again, I apologize for the general question.

```
import os


def clear():
    if os.name == 'nt':
        os.system('cls')
    else:
        os.system('clear')


num_list = []
user_nums = 0
while True:
    clear()
    print('Type DONE to calculate the average of the numbers you entered!')
    if num_list:
        print('Here are the numbers you want to find the average of:{}'.format(num_list))
    try:
        nums = input("What numbers do you want to find the average of? ")
        if nums.upper() == 'DONE':
            clear()
            print('The average is: {}'.format(user_nums/len(num_list)))
        float(nums)
        if isinstance(nums, (float, int)):
            num_list.append(nums)
            user_nums += nums

    except ValueError:
        print('Please only enter numbers.')
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem has nothing to do with `os`. `nums` is a string (of type `str`). You *think* you convert it to a float, but you do not assign the result to any variable and it is lost. After the conversion, `nums` is still a string.

`float(nums)` must be `nums=float(nums)`. When Python attempts to execute this assignment, it either succeeds (and then there is no point in checking `nums`'s type again) or fails, and then there is an exception.